# library(table1) :extract the best quality table as word

Tags: html, r, pdf, output, cpu-word

I have already used Library table 1 for my descriptive table. my problem is about exporting the output table for the Word document.I dont know how to extract the best quality table.( I dont have any problem to knit to HTML but I have problem with exporting tables for word and PDF.)
My bookdown settings are as follows:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Marjan"
date: "3/29/2021"
output:
  pdf_document:
    toc: yes
  word_document:
    toc: yes
  html_document:
    toc: yes
    toc_float:
      collapsed: no
      smooth_scroll: no
---
```

This is a subset of my code :

````
```{r echo = FALSE, results = FALSE, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE, error = FALSE}
table1(~ factor(sex ) + age + factor(race) + education +factor(marital) + bmi + factor(smoke) + activity +factor(dominant)+allgrip
       | cancer, data=main)

label(main$sex)<- "Sex % (N)"
label(main$age)<- "Age"
label(main$race)<- "Race(N)"
label(main$education) <- "Education % (N)"
label(main$marital)<- "Marital status % (N)"
label(main$bmi)<- "Body mass index (kg/m2)(SD)"
label(main$smoke)<- "Current daily smoker % (N)"
label(main$activity) <- " Work activity"
label(main$dominant)<- "Dominant hand % (N)"
label(main$allgrip) <- "Grip Strength/Kg"
table1(~ sex + age + race + education +marital
       +bmi + smoke + activity +dominant+allgrip 
       | cancer, data=main,overall=F, topclass="Rtable1-zebra",render.missing=NULL)

knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```
````

[image]

Comment: If you could show an example of the table

Comment: I couldn't add a photo , here. Could I send it by email? Thanks.